# Removing white spaces and comments from asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a Website project with a lot of aspx sites. I would like to find out is there any tool that will allow me to remove all white spaces and comments from the aspx files? I don't want to do it on run-time because it's not performance optimal. I would like to do it just before deployment.

Is there any ready tool, or should I write a simple console app, that would use REGEX to eliminate the unnecessary white spaces and comments?

Regards,
Adam

Comment: Regex, lots of aspx code, trimming chars = recipe for disaster

Comment: (1) Forget regular expressions, very very bad idea (2) There are similar questions on stackoverflow, check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255008/minify-html-output-of-asp-net-application

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose? Obfuscation?

If you're just trying to reduce the size of HTTP responses to the end user, you are much better off telling the web server to [use compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347437.aspx) on your output. This zips the spaces away to nothing and gives much smaller results than ‘minification’.

(Unless you are retaining loads of `<!-- comments -->` in which case you should simply change them to `<%-- server-side comments --%>`.)

Don't try to process ASP.NET with regex. Neither HTML nor aspx-templates are regular languages and together they are much, much more complicated than regex can handle. Naïve approaches like looking for spaces outside of `<[^>]*>` constructs are very likely to mess up your pages.

Comment: It's because the code have a lot of comments inside, and there just to many aspx files to remove this comments by hand. I think that removing them would reduce the output by around 30%, and it's quite a lot. I think that I will try with some more complicated regexes.

Comment: You could match `<!--(.*?)-->` and replace with `<%--\1--%>` across your actual work copy of the files (not as a deployment option); you will probably break something, but at least you're likely to find out that you've broken it more quickly. Or hack up a script that will show you each match it finds before it replaces it, allowing you to Y-Y-Y-Y through them with a little review. Either way, output compression is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is no need to do it on run-time. Because it can be done on compile-time. Check this link out: http://omari-o.blogspot.com/2009/09/aspnet-white-space-cleaning-with-no.html