# HTML Minification for ASP.net Webpages

Tags: html, asp.net, minify, asp.net-webpages

Has anyone got any way to Minify HTML on a ASP.net WEBPAGES site. 
I have the .JS and .Css Minifed but cant fine anything for the HTML.

I have found along of options for MVC and webforms, I have also tried puting these onto the Webpages framwork but none of them have worked.

I hope someone can help. Remember webpages not MVC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minify Html output of ASP.NET Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255008/minify-html-output-of-asp-net-application)

Comment: Hi @MedhdiDehghani this is not a duplicate, i have tried all the suggestions on that post, some of them aren't even available any more.

Comment: Hi, how about [How to minify aspx pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829659/how-to-minify-aspx-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I had this done a couple of weeks ago for mine.  In MVC there is a nuget for minifying cshtml files but considering webforms, here is the fix.  There is an open source [htmlminifier](https://github.com/deanhume/html-minifier) available to minify html.
1) Please clone this project and run it to create an exe inside the bin folder

[image: htmlminifier exe]

2) Right click your project and click 'Unload Project'
3) Right click on the unloaded project and choose edit .csproj
4) Add this target at the end of the file

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="">
    <Message Text="Minifying files.....$(DirectoryGroups)" />
    <Exec Command="c:\Users\Admin\htmlminifier.exe C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\htmlminifier" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

5) Reload the project
6) Build and publish your website.  The minification is done.
**Before minification**
[image]

**After minification**

[image]

Comment: Hi staticvoidmain,

Comment: Hi staticvoidmain,
Thank you for your help, i will try this, but i am using WebPages framework not WebForms. Al tho they all shear a lot of similarities there are differences. The info above is detailed tho so i will giv this ago. thank you.

Comment: @MatthewMccall - It is suggested to use both minification and gzipping to get the best performance.  [Here](http://madskristensen.net/post/effects-of-gzipping-vs-minifying-html-files) are the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article here on how to do it
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/08/15/adding-web-optimization-to-a-web-pages-site/

In the _AppStart.cshtml add code like

```
@using System.Web.Optimization;

@{
     var bundles = BundleTable.Bundles;

     bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", 
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

}
```

Then in your web page

```
@using System.Web.Optimization;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@Page.Title - My ASP.NET Web Page</title>    

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css", "~/Content/css");    

        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />    

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
```