# How to filter and compress output HTML in MVC3?

Tags: html, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, global-filter

In my MVC3 project all the pages have the following HTML as output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/icons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="well">
            <h2>Test</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <footer>
        <p>&copy;</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, how can I make a filter to trim rows and remove blank lines, to get the output like the following example...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My app</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Content/icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/Content/icons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="well">
<h2>Test</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<footer>
<p>&copy;</p>
</footer>
</div>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255008/minify-html-output-of-asp-net-application.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC, 
you have can using action filter , caching & compression for fast load your site.

Please view link [filter caching and compression (C#)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx)

Hope it will be useful for you